# Area 51 Service Unavailable 503 on all pages

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51

Is it just me getting a 503 server error from Area 51? I get it whenever I click on a proposal link.

Update - all pages on Area 51 return this:

[image]

```
Service Unavailable
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

- [downforeveryoneorjustme](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/area51.stackexchange.com) (Offline)
- [isitdown](http://isitdown.co.uk/area51.stackexchange.com) (Online)
- [isitdownrightnow](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/area51.stackexchange.com.html) (Online)

Comment: I have the same issue on all pages too. My best bet is to wait this one out a bit.

Comment: Most likely, but it is sensible to alert the devs to it.

Comment: Very true. Has this same scenario happened occasionally on Area51 before?

Comment: I've never seen it...

Comment: No repro, working fine here.

Comment: Still down for me :/ To confirm - is this page working: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85908/gold-prospecting

Comment: No repro for me: this is my 
tracert: `5    17 ms    18 ms    18 ms  80.249.211.140
6    18 ms    18 ms    17 ms  104.16.12.13`

Comment: I'm able to ping the server tho...

Comment: Try viewing without being logged it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no luck, still http error 503.

Comment: Traceroute: `6  104.16.13.13 (104.16.13.13)  61.521 ms  33.423 ms  32.430 ms`

Comment: Still down for me in Chrome + Firefox and Dooble (signed in and not), but I can ping and traceroute. I'm in the UK - where are you?

Comment: And online checkers are giving mixed results: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/area51.stackexchange.com and http://isitdown.co.uk/area51.stackexchange.com and http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/area51.stackexchange.com.html

Comment: @Tim Ah, something to note; I'm in France and it was down for me as well. Maybe it was only over Europe.

Comment: Sounds like it - I can't think why it would be a consistent thing. Otherwise sometimes you'd reach the bad server, and other times not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with one of our servers in the network.  It has been reset and should now be back in rotation.

Comment: Yep, back up :) Why was it a some people / not others?

Comment: Some people hit the bad server, others didn't, @Tim.

Comment: Just curious, was Area 51 the only victim, or did the issue affect more sites?

Comment: Area51 was the only victim in this case.